# How to generate cucumber report name with the feature name in rubymine and cucumber.yml

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rubymine

The cucumber reports are being created with the date time as shown here in `cucumber.yml`:

```
default: RDEE_BROWSER=chrome --no-source --color --format pretty --format html --out testresults/<%= Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") %>-reportch.html --retry 2 --tags @current_tests
```

But what I would like to do is also include the feature name, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest / best way of doing this (assuming you're looking at the long-term solution). Is to have this done as a 2nd step and using standard fileutils.

You should technically create the report with a bland known name i.e. placeholder.html - And then in your next step rename / move it alongside the requisite name.

You could do this in a rake-task or by using jenkins e.t.c. Write your desired name to an Environment variable like REPORT_NAME=`this` and then save this inside a ruby method invocation in your before/after hook